# How to get SPF and TXT records for a domain?

Tags: java, dns

I am working on a mailing service.
Is there a way by which I can get hostnames which are authorized to send emails on behalf of the given domain (SPF records or TXT records).

There is dnsjava library which returns the SPF, TXT, MX, etc. records but It doesn't do nested lookups if the mechanism in the record is of type redirect, MX, ptr, etc.

There is an apache/james-jspf library but it only authenticate the email sender.

There are libraries in python like SPF2IP. But it invokes a new system process to resolve the SPF which is very costly computationally.

Comment: In an SPF records you can have IP addresses not just hostnames, and you also have the include feature which means having to do some more DNS queries.

Comment: Yes, @PatrickMevzek I want to find a library which can make recursive calls and give me IP, hostnames, etc.

Comment: unfortunately asking for library recommendations is offtopic here...

Comment: A code that does a recursive lookup on directives in TXT/SPF record will also work for me. I searched on google for days but could not find anything that solves my problem.

Comment: Modifying the apache/james-jspf library to extract SPF and TXT records and I will make my changes open-source so that others can use it as well